# The correct syntax for map data type in age

Tags: graph, apache-age

What is the correct syntax for the map age data type

```
{‘name’: ‘John’, ‘age’: 23}
```

Or

```
{‘name’: ‘John’; ‘age’: 23}
```

Pay attention to the separator `,` and `;`. Both syntax have been used in the age docs. Are both valid or it’s just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You need the comma separator, `;` is a typo

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo for sure. You should use comma as a properties separator.
In action:
using `;` separator outputs (not working):

```
test=# select * from cypher('test_graph', $$
test$# CREATE (n:Person {name:'mohamed'; age:12}) RETURN n; $$) as (res agtype);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2: CREATE (n:Person {name:'mohamed'; age:12}) RETURN n $$) as ...
```

using `,` separator outputs (working):

```
select * from cypher('test_graph', $$
CREATE (n:Person {name:'mohamed', age:12}) RETURN n $$) as (res agtype);
                                               res                              
                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Person", "properties": {"age": 12, "name": "m
ohamed"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

Referring to the Apache AGE manual: https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#accessing-list-elements-in-maps

Answer (score 1):

using separator `,` is the correct way in the map syntax like the following example

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    WITH {int_key: 1, float_key: 1.0, numeric_key: 1::numeric, bool_key: true, string_key: 'Value'} as m
    RETURN m
$$) AS (m agtype);
```

Ref: [Data Types in a AGE docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#literal-maps-with-simple-data-types)

Answer (score 1):

For the map, you need to use ',' and not ':'.

This is explained in the [link](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#map).

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax in your case would be:

> {'name': 'John', 'age': 23}

The use of semicolon as a separator is wrong. It is basically a typo or error.

Answer (score 1):

The below query explains how to make a map using the cypher query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
WITH {key: 1, lenght_value: 1.0, numeric_key: 1::numeric, bool_key: true, 
name: 'Waleed Ahmed Shahid'} as m
RETURN m
$$) AS (m agtype);
```

We can also create a map with composite data types.
The below query explains that:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
WITH {listKey: [{inner: 'Map1'}, {inner: 'Map2'}], mapKey: {i: 0}} as m
RETURN m
$$) AS (m agtype);
```

You can see from the above example that a map is being made and the nested maps and other variables have also been created in the above example.

You can consult the documentation for more understanding.

[Documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html#map)

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax for the map data type is the comma `(,)` as the separator between key-value pairs. Using `(;)` is a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, For map age data type, you must use (,) and (;) is a typo.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    WITH {int_key: 1, float_key: 1.0, numeric_key: 1::numeric, bool_key: true, string_key: 'Value'} as m
    RETURN m
$$) AS (m agtype);
```

You can follow [this tutorial](https://joefagan.github.io/age_docs/#literal-maps-with-simple-data-types) & [official docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html).

Answer (score -1):

The one with comma separator is valid not with semi-colon.

Answer (score -1):

Apache AGE is primarily based on the property graph model and the correct syntax for the map data type is to use the comma (,) as the separator between key-value pairs. The semicolon (;) is not a valid separator.

The correct syntax for a map data type in AGE would be:

```
{ 'name': 'John', 'age': 23 }
```

This is a simple example showcasing the use of a map to store and represent the properties of a product entity in the AGE syntax.

Answer (score -1):

It surely is a typo, comma is a valid separator and not semicolon.